# MultiResourceItemReader - read only specific files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a task that I need to load to the database only new CSV files. if the file was already loaded to the database then this file should be ignored. Currently, I am loading all the CSV files regardless.

```
// daily/*.csv
@Value("${dailyExportDirPath}")
private Resource[] inputResources;

@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader(FieldSetMapper<DailyExport> testClassRowMapper) {

    MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    multiResourceItemReader.setName("dailyExportMultiReader");
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader(testClassRowMapper));
    multiResourceItemReader.setStrict(true);
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
    return multiResourceItemReader;
}
```

I was thinking to create a table that will contain all the files that where already loaded.  So instead of initiate a resources array with all the existing CSV’s from the directory, the job will create a resource array that will contain only the new reports.

**all reports in directory – reports in database = new reports that need to load.**

How can I optimize the resources array so they will contain only the relevant files meaning the new ones?

Thank you

Comment: A common technique is to move processed files to a separate (archive) directory after the job with a listener for example. With this in place, your job would only process new files. Another solution would be to check the previous job executions meta-data to get the files that have been processed and filter them in the current run. Otherwise, a meta-data table is also a good option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've one table for file metadata, and another for file content (with a FK back to file metadata table), you can simply use the current date for file id in the metadata table. Then database will fail any attempt to insert duplicate rows in the file metadata table, you catch it, and keep processing other files.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Not exactly but it is a valid idea.